# Why "ain't I" and "aren't I" instead of "amn't I"?

Tags: etymology

Why do we say "ain't I" or "aren't I" instead of "amn't I"? What's the history of this usage? Are there any other similar patterns in English?

I'm guessing it has something to do with the dispreference of two consecutive nasal consonants, but a more authoritative answer would be great.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ain't

Comment: @z7sg Are you suggesting it's "General Reference"? Because if that simple search explains it, then it is, in my opinion.

Comment: @Ale No I don't think it is general reference but I think the 'similar patterns' part is too wide a scope.  I am surprised nobody has asked about "ain't" before, it's an interesting question.  The wiktionary is a good starting point.

Comment: What does "General Reference" mean? Is that a tag or a suggestion to close? @z7sg: by "similar patterns", I meant other cases where an English word with two consecutive nasal sounds evolved into another word -- why is this too wide a scope?

Comment: @grautur: General Refence is a close-vote reason, which states: "_This question is too basic; it can be definitively and permanently answered by a single link to a standard internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information._"

Comment: _Amn't_ is a contraction of _am not_ that is used in Scottish Irish. It's then used, but it's not largely used.

Comment: In any case, one reason why I'm not satisfied with the Wiktionary link is that... it doesn't really tell me anything! All it's basically saying is that am not contracted to an't (instead of amn't, for whatever reason), and then an't became ain't and aren't (...and I already knew that these are the modern contractions of am not). Why these particular contractions? Is the first an instance of the Great Vowel Shift? Is the latter due to rhoticization?

Comment: I've heard *amn't* occasionally but only in a particular ditty: "Gee, amn't I lucky/haven't got a face like yours, brother".

Comment: Both are correct, but the usage of aren't I is wider than the usage of amn't I. Also, amn't I is mostly used in Scotland/Northern Ireland. For more information, read [this article](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-amn1.htm) from World Wide Words.

Comment: You should try going to the Black Country (English West Midlands) where, in certain dialects amn't is alive and well as well as y'am to mean "you are" and many other exciting uses the verb "to be" - very confusing to an outsider! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:If_yowm_saft_enuff.jpg

Comment: Gotta **am** in Black Country sometime.

Comment: Some of the old-timers among non-native English speakers weren't even aware of *aren't I*/ *amn't I*  until recently. It has always been *am I not*.

Answer (score 18):

Here’s the relevant extract from [‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052162181X):

> Historically speaking, both *ain’t* and *aren’t* are probably
>   descended from *an’t*, recorded during the late C17 as the regular
>   contraction. Sound changes of the C18 affected the pronunciation of
>   the vowel "a" before nasal consonants, raising it in some dialects,
>   and lowering and retracting it in others. While *ain’t* is a product
>   of the first process, *aren’t* represents the second in terms of
>   British (*r*-less) pronunciation – though not in general American. If
>   only *an’t* was still available, it would avoid the grammatical
>   discomfort and provide a nonstigmatized alternative to *ain’t*.

Answer (score 12):

The NOAD has a note about using *aren't*, and *amn't*:

> The contraction *aren't* is used in standard English to mean "am not" in questions, as in "I'm right, aren't I?" Outside of questions, it is incorrect to use *aren't* to mean "am not" (for example, "I aren't going" is clearly wrong). The nonstandard (although logical) form *amn't* is restricted to Scottish, Irish, and dialect use.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So "aren't I" is the only acceptable option, or the others are valid as well?

Comment: It depends on which language: Scottish uses _amn't_, but standard English uses _aren't_.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for this pronunciation is due to the accent of the people from which it originated from, the Cockney accent:

> 1706, originally a contraction of am not,  and in proper use with that sense until it began to be used as a generic contraction for are not, is not,  etc., in early 19c. Cockney dialect of London

It was actually originally *amn't*, as can be seen [here:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ain%27t)

> Origin: 
>   1770–80; variant of amn't  (contraction of am not ) by loss of m  and raising with compensatory lengthening of "a"

The reason it is in popular usage today can be seen in this excerpt:

> popularized by representations of this in Dickens, etc., which led to the word being banished from correct English.

"Ain't" is used because it is more popular, and also, it is easier to pronounce.