# Is "aren't I" correct grammar?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, contractions

Since "amn't I" is so clunky, is "aren't I" grammatically correct?  Or is the only way to say this "Am I not"?

Comment: @waiwai: The linked question does not address whether "aren't I" is considered grammatically correct.  All it establishes is that "aren't I" and "ain't I" are preferred because they're easier to say.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i

Comment: I suggest using the "flag" option (if available) to bring issues like this up to moderators directly. Waiwai probably just skimmed the related question before closing this one (I know I have done that a few times myself) without realizing that this question asks something not addressed in the other.

Comment: Yes .... but from where does it come? Are there any historical references?

Comment: It's not grammatically correct. It's supposed to be,"am I not?" There are,however,instances when you should switch between "am I" and "am I not?"


Incorrect example: I'm so dark,aren't I?
Correct example: I'm so dark,am I not?


Incorrect Example: I'm dying,aren't I?
Correct Example: I'm dying,am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NOAD reports that *aren't* is the contraction of *are not*, and *am not*; in the latter case, it is used only in questions.

> Why aren't I being given a pay raise?

The *Collins English Dictionary* says the same, but it says that using [*aren't*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/arent) as contraction of *am not* is informal, and chiefly British.

> 2. informal, mainly British (used in interrogative sentences)
>    am not

Comment: I'm American, and "aren't I" doesn't seem to be "chiefly British" to me... I wonder why Collins says that.

Comment: It keeps saying it, even on the online version.

Answer (score 3):

*Aren't I?* is standard English as the negative interrogative of *I am.*  So it is correct.

*Ain't I?* is also common though regarded as a lower register.  *Am I not?* sounds far too picky. *I am, init?* is also used, though I hate it. *Amn't I* might be logical, but only seems to exist, if at all, in Scottish or Irish dialect.

Comment: Could you cite an authority on the subject?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractions_of_negated_auxiliary_verbs_in_English#Colloquial_contractions has a discussion

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's still not clear.  Are you saying that it _is_ correct grammar?

Comment: @drm65: he said that _"Aren't I?"_ is correct grammar (accepted in formal and informal settings), but that _"Ain't I?"_ is appropriate only in a very, very informal setting (i.e. not correct for writing, but it is exactly what people say in certain informal contexts).

Comment: I have also never heard "I am, init?"  What is that from?

Comment: @drm65. *Aren't I?* is correct grammar, indeed standard.  *Init?* is London youth vernacular adopted from immigrants, used as a universal negative question word, derived from *isn't it?* but used for all three persons, singular and plural, and something I discourage.

Comment: How/why is "aren't" the negative of "am"?  You wouldn't say "I are going" or "Are I going", you'd say "I am going" or "Am I going", so it makes no sense to suddenly switch to "are"; it *should* be "Amn't I going" or "I amn't going". English is such a mess, if enough people keep doing things wrong for long enough, it magically becomes "correct". The day that dictionaries start adding "would of" as acceptable is the day I quit speaking English. 

Answer (score 0):

Just say "am I not", which carries no error other than causing one to sound like Barbara Eden portraying "Jeannie". Easy.

Answer (score -7):

Just because people say "aren't I" to avoid saying "ain't I," the original contraction of "am I not," does not make it correct. It's an odious "error if pretension." What's so difficult about "amn't I" (no harder to say than "wasn't I") - that form would be graceful and logical, so let's start using it.

Comment: There's nothing difficult about _amn’t I_, but as was already mentioned, it simply does not exist in Modern English, except in Ireland and Scotland. Just because you personally don't like something and it isn't ‘original’ doesn't make it a mistake or an error. And _ain’t I_ is not a contraction of _am I not_, but of _am not I_.

Comment: How is "aren't" I pretentious? It's still a contraction. I think "am I not" would be the actually pretentious version...