# "Aren't I" vs "Amn't I"

Tags: verbs, questions, contractions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why “ain't I” and “aren't I” instead of “amn't I”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i)

Why do we say "aren't I" rather than "amn't I"? Is it purely for ease or pronunciation?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i

Comment: @z7sgѪ: I'd go farther and say that this is an outright duplicate of that earlier question.