# Why isn’t singular ‘they’ used with 3Sg verb forms?

Tags: verb-agreement, singular-they

There are many (duplicate) questions about the acceptance, popularity and history of singular *they* (and *their*, *them* and *themself*) around here, it even got a tag of its own. If I didn’t miss anything, however, the proper verb form hasn’t been questioned yet.

As we all know, English third person singular pronouns (*it, she, he* and *one, +body*), names (*Alice, Bob, …*) and nouns (*student, teacher, …*) demand the *+(e)s* suffix be added to the finite verb form in simple present, where some auxiliary verbs have a “special” form (*is* < **bes* / **ares* and *has* < **haves*). All other subjects don’t, including plural third person pronoun *they*.

When the plural *you* replaced *thou* (with *thee*, *thy / thine*), the other marked verb form that had remained in English – i.e. suffix *+(e)st* or *+t* – vanished, too. The first and second persons only ever appear as pronouns (*I, we; you*), not names or nouns, so there was no strong inclination to keep the verbal inflection.

The second person precedent would suggest that singular *they* be used with uninflected verb forms which is how it’s usually encountered in the wild. Assuming that *they* someday replaces *he* and *she* (and maybe *it*) it would lead to disagreement with the words the pronoun stands in for:

> 1. Alice         **goes** to her   place  by herself.
> 2. Bob           **goes** to his   place  by himself.
> 3. Alice and Bob **go**   to their place  by themselves. – *(common)*
> 4. Alice and Bob **go**   to their places by themselves. – *(separate)*
>
> ---
>
> 1. She  **goes** to her   place  by herself.
> 2. He   **goes** to his   place  by himself.
> 3. They **go**   to their place  by themselves.
> 4. They **go**   to their places by themselves.
>
> ---
>
> 1. They ?**goes** to their place  by themself.
> 2. *ditto*
> 3. They  **go**   to their place  by themselves.
> 4. They  **go**   to their places by themselves.
>
> ---
>
> 1. They ?**go** to their place  by ?themselves.
> 2. *ditto*
> 3. They  **go** to their place  by  themselves.
> 4. They  **go** to their places by  themselves.

So why doesn’t singular *they* afford *s* on present-tense verbs like all other third person singular subjects do?

I learned about singular *they* only long after I had been taught English as a second language in school. That’s why it’s still a conscious decision to use it and hence I could easily adapt to use *s* forms with it, but would that sound and look funny / strange / wrong to native speakers?

Comment: I’m not sure I follow your question at all. The second plural became a generic second person, but plural form of the verb was kept, which is what one would expect to happen. When French _vous_ or German _Sie_ started to be used for singular entities [ignoring the anachronism inherent in that statement], they didn’t take over singular agreement—they remain plural. Add to that the fact that second-person forms/pronouns are much more likely, typologically, to be ousted than a singular–plural distinction in the third person. I don’t see why _they_ would ever take over from _he/she/it_ [cont’d -->]

Comment: [--> cont’d] nor why it would start to take singular agreement if it did. Singular _they_ is just using a plural pronoun with a singular referent in the same way that French _vous_ or German _Sie_ both do. That doesn’t make it a singular pronoun for agreement purposes.

Comment: For example: *It's "you are", "you were"*, *"you have"* and NOT *"you is", "you was"*, *"you has"* (well... that's the "rule")

Comment: To answer your question directly, yes, it would look 'funny, strange and wrong' to a native speaker.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I tried to explain why I can see that happen for the first and second person and I tried to explain why it leads to incongruences with the third person. Formal 2Sg _sie_ in German is taken from 3Pl, not 2Pl (like English _you_ and French _vous_), by the way, which makes it a slightly different case. Also note, that singular _they_ then works differently than proposed artificial gender-neutral substitutes like *_xe_ – and I wonder why.

Comment: I’m aware that _Sie_ is from the third person (like Spanish _Usted_, Portuguese _você_, Italian _lei_, Danish/Norwegian _De_, Hungarian _ön_, etc.). That doesn’t change that it still takes its original agreement. No pronoun has changed its agreement when usurping another in any language I can think of (excepting Old Norse _við_ ‘we’, which took over plural agreement when its original dual inflection was lost entirely). And as I said, obliterating the singular–plural distinction is typologically _much_ rarer in the third person than in the first and second.

Comment: As a similar parallel, the _pluralis maiestatis_ or ‘royal _we_’ uses the plural pronoun _we_ to refer to a single person instead of the singular pronoun _I_; but Queen Victoria didn’t say “We am not amused”. I can’t see **any** reason why _they_ should behave any differently from _we_ and _you_ when it is used with a singular referent.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The actual alternative would have been _you art/beest, you wast/wert, you hast_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet For a similar reason that gave us _yourself_ and _themself_ or the number distinction of third-person _sie_ in German (i.e. _sie geht_ SgFem, _sie gehen_ Pl).

Comment: The _self_ forms are a completely different kettle of fish. They deal with the logical reference of the pronoun, not its verbal agreement. _Sie_ (fem.sg.) and _sie_ (pl.) in German happen to have coalesced, but they’re not originally just the same pronoun being used in two different ways. It’s just that regular sound change in the history of German caused _sie_, _siu_, and _sio_ (once distinct) to all fall together as [ziː], just like what happened with _diu/die/dio_, etc.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Notice how when English uses *one* to mean *we*, or when French does so with *on*, one does not change the agreement. I agree that *yourself, themself* opposes *yourselves, themselves* in referential agreement; I believe there is some history with *ourself, ourselves* as well. Note that ES *Usted* / PT *você* / CA *vostè* were originally ***terms of courtesy***  ( *vostra/vuestra merced*; hence the abbreviation *Vd.*) rather like how we use *Your Honor*, and so naturally take 3s agreement; all three also have plural forms (*Ustedes, vocês, vostès*) with 3p not 3s agreement.

Comment: @Crissov I mean no offence, but I believe your question stems from the ***unconscionable negligence*** of inferior ESL texts&instructors who omitted from your education a standard pronominal form used by native speakers over the last 700 years. You are therefore acquiring it inorganically, out of its natural sequence and conditions. Because this path is so far removed from how native speakers acquire it during ages 1–3, your question seems super-bizarre to us, something we would never consider. It so clashes with how pronouns and verbs fit together for us that we cannot imagine it otherwise.

Comment: @tchrist No offense taken, although I wouldn’t it attribute to the quality of my educators and their material, but to the potentially insightful distance everyone brings to each language they learns. ;)

Comment: [they was](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22they+was%22&tbm=bks) on Google books produces 915,000 hits. It won't be long before we'll be hearing [*they has*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22they+has%22&tbm=bks&start=0). Oh wait, we do! (descriptivists/linguists call similar non-standard English, dialects)

Comment: @Mari-LouA All of those examples are from 'non-standard' varieties of English. The problem with that is that in those varieties *was* and *has* are the standard third person *plural* forms. It doesn't really have anything to do with 3rd person singular *they*. None of those examples are examples of singular they. On top of this, for at least a few of the varieties illustrated, the third person *singular* form is, erm, *were* and *have*! :)

Comment: @Araucaria "S/he *was*" not "S/he were"? 3rd person singular, right? Oh, the VARIETIES. I just wanted to give a little encouragement to the OP, who's to say how English will develop and change over the next twenty years.

Comment: You’ll find dialects that have generalised the unmarked form and dialects that have generalised the marked form with _-s_. You find “I am”, “I be”, “I is” and even “I are” as the standard form in various dialects. The only variation I admit I’ve never come across is using first-singular agreement with the other persons; so no “you am” or “they am”.

Comment: If you say "They is over there," I can just about guarantee you that a lot more people will have a problem with "They is" than will object to singular *they*.

Comment: Even with  *singular they*, the word *they* is still treated grammatically as a plural.

Comment: @ScotM are there any rules/sources you can point to? If so **please** post an answer.

Comment: @phenry I'm looking for grammar rules, not what's popular. (unless you subscribe to a descriptive theory of language [as opposed to prescriptive], and then you can post an answer and make that case.)

Comment: [A Wiktionary discussion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Talk:they) addresses this. Also, Google Ngrams for 'they is here', 'they are here' flatline for the former.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is often said that verbs in English inflect to agree with the person and number of the subject. Now *person* here cannot be construed as an actual property of the subject. We cannot say for example that the first person is the person who's speaking and the second person is the person being spoken to or any ideas like that. If we do not use an actual pronoun to represent the person speaking, then the verb will not inflect in any way to agree with the '*speaker-hood*' of the subject.

- *Araucaria am writing this. (wrong)
- *The reader are reading this. (wrong)

In the sentences above, even though *Araucaria* refers to the person who is currently speaking to you, in other words me, we cannot use a 'first person' form of the verb. Similarly, even though *the reader* refers to you, the 'listener', we cannot use a second person form of the verb. When we use common nouns we do not see agreement for person.

Although with common nouns, and proper nouns English verbs inflect to agree with number, they do not agree with any other property of the noun, including the relation to speaker or listener or third party. However, verbs *do* seem to inflect according to which *pronoun* is being used. In other words pronouns *override* the normal agreement of verbs with subjects:

- I am writing this
- You are reading this.

The examples above are fine, not because *I* refers to the person who is speaking, and *you* are the person reading, but because verbs inflect in accordance with specific pronouns, and these pronouns override the normal agreement that we see with common nouns.

In the Original Poster's question, this issue is disguised, because when verbs agree with third person singular and plural pronouns, they mimic their behaviour with common nouns. However, this is just an illusion. As with the pronouns *I*, *you* and *we*, 'they' also overrides the normal agreement of verbs with common nouns. Whether used with singular or plural meaning, pronouns always dictate the agreement of the verb according to which actual pronoun they are. *They* always takes a 'third person plural' form of the verb.

This same phenomenon can be seen with the pronoun *one*. Whether used to reflect first person, second person, or people in general, *one* always takes the same verb agreement, the one we wrongly describe as 'third person singular'. The same also applies to royal *we*.

The answer to the Original Poster's question, therefore, is that verbs won't inflect to reflect the *singularity* of singular *they*, because although verbs agree with number when they have common noun subjects, using a pronoun as subject will override the normal common noun agreement and cause the verb to agree according to which specific pronoun is being used. It wouldn't be a good idea to use 'third person singular' forms with *they*, because it would just be ungrammatical. It wouldn't reflect anything about the meaning of *they*. The agreement of English verbs with pronouns never reflects any semantic property of the pronoun in the first place!

Will the agreement taken by *they* change in the future? I don't think so, but I don't know, and I don't know anyone who really does!

[Readers who are interested in this question might also be interested in: [Why is "be" the only English verb that inflects for grammatical person, not just for grammatical number like all the rest of them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204950/pronoun-usage-and-conjugation/205006#205006) - although it is a slightly strange question!]

Comment: What exactly is _relecft_ a typo of? _Relate_?!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks! I thought you'd disappeared! - or were getting on with uni stuff or something (- like I'm meant to be ...)

Comment: I’m supposed to be … that and work has been keeping me ridiculously busy. So busy, it seems, that I can’t even seem to properly offset an f in a typo three places to the left!

Answer (score 9):

To put it simply: "singular *they*" is *syntactically plural*, and *semantically singular*. Just like *trousers*. This occasional disconnect between semantics and syntax is not unique to English.

Sometimes these things do change, especially when not very recognisable (such as *data* moving from being plural to being singular). But the change is in general slow due to conventionality of language (tendency of native speaker community that keeps the language stable).

Comment: I feel like you're missing a conclusion here. You lay out some evidence, and then do not draw an answer from it. “‘singular *they*’ is *syntactically plural*, and *semantically singular* [...] just like *trousers*,” sooo.... what? Which verb form should be used? You rely on the reader to supply the actual conclusion, presumably based on knowledge of which verb form is used with *trousers*.

Comment: @KRyan: The OP already knows which form is currently correct in Standard English ("So why doesn’t singular they afford s on present-tense verbs like all other third person singular subjects do?"). The question was "why", not "which".

Answer (score 2):

When we use singular *they*, this does not change the fact that the word is *they*. The word *they*, like the words *I* (singular) and *you* (singular and plural), is followed by the uninflected verb-form.

Comment: You’re arguing, like @JanusBahsJacquet above, that verbal inflection is bound to the lexemic nature of a word (or at least of a pronoun) and not its syntactic function (“logical reference”). That may well be so. I’m just arguing that the fact that all other proposed gender-neutral alternatives to _s/he_ and all singular nouns and names agreeing with _he/she/it_ would suggest otherwise. I also argued that unified _you_ doesn’t form a true precedent.

Comment: Whatever you argue, the fact is that *they" does take an uninflected verb-form. Singular *you* seems to be to be a reasonable example of such a thing happening previously. The singularity of proposed gender-neutral terms is irrelevant - they have been devised as singular forms.

Comment: @tunny It doesn't really seem to make sense to say that *they* is followed by an uninflected verb form. For example in the present simple, *BE* has three different forms according to which pronoun or noun is being used. The fast that several subjects take the same  form of verb doesn't mean that those forms are uninflected! (Same goes by extension for normal verbs in the present simple)

Comment: @Araucaria -  The first form/base form/dictionary entry form of the all verbs has no inflections for mood, tense or number. Don't you think that it's reasonable to say that it is this uninflected form of all verbs (except BE)  that is used for all persons in the present simple except the third person singular?

Comment: @tunny Not quite really, imo, because there's too many excepts in there. But more importantly, inflection really means to have some kind of contrastive form in relation to other forms. And especially in the third person in particular, there are two contrasting forms in the present simple ... Though I get completely why you put it that way. :)