# how to ignore gender nicely in english? can i make the sentence plural?

Tags: grammatical-gender, singular-they

why is this possible to replace:

`someone removed his/her` with `someone removed their`

can I also change:

`The user clicks on the button. He/She then sees..` with
`The user clicks on the button. They then sees..`

or how would you ignore gender more elegantly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This called a [singular they](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) and its use is common

It remains syntactically plural though semantically singular,  so you would need to end with "*They then see ...*" - see the discussion in [Why isn’t singular ‘they’ used with 3Sg verb forms?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207502/why-isn-t-singular-they-used-with-3sg-verb-forms)

There are many alternatives, including "*The user clicks on the button and  then sees ...*"