# If it's "I am" and not "I are", why is it "I aren't" instead of "I amn't"?

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs, be

I've been taught to say "I am" and "I aren't", but that doesn't make any sense to me. I think it should have been "I amn't" as am+not=amn't, but why isn't it?

Comment: "I aren't" is wrong. Who taught you to say this?  You should say "I'm not."

Comment: [I think this is related.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i) The short version is it seems like amn't was changed to ain't for pronunciation reasons, which was ultimately deigned "2 crood" for polite discussion..Am seems like the only helping verb without a valid not contraction as a result...

Comment: In some variants of English (particularly Irish English), _amn’t_ is in fact quite commonly heard. In most variants, though, it's not found at all. @chaslyfromUK That is not true. _Aren’t_ is an accepted contraction of _am not_. Just like there's a difference (in form, if not in meaning) between _he’s not_ and _he isn’t_, there’s a difference between _I’m not_ and _I aren’t_.

Comment: @Tonepoet Not only related, but actually an exact duplicate.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: But in all dialects I know of that use "aren't" for the first-person singular, its use is restricted to questions with inversion: we'd see "Aren't I" but never "I aren't."

Answer (score 1):

To contract "I am not" to 2 syllables, there are two alternatives: either combine "am" with "I", or "am" with "not". If the latter were adopted, "I amn't" would indeed be a reasonable choice. For whatever reason, though, the former has become the norm, producing "I'm not" as the standard contraction (and definitely not "I are not". "Are" is used with second person singular and plural, 1st person plural, and 3rd person plural. It is not used with 1st person singular.)