# Amn’t - where does it occur in the US?

Tags: american-english, contractions

We moved to CA from Norfolk, VA as children. Our parents and grandparents are college educated yet we four all said “amn’t,” to the shock of our CA neighbors.

We no longer say it but I wondered why we all said this in 1967?

All I can find in an online search is that they use it in Ireland and Scotland.

Note: My second and third generation Irish parents from Boston and St. Louis did not use it. Is it common in southern Virginia?

Comment: Though not very often, and not very well. The most likely thing is that this was a family usage that persisted and was possibly unexceptionable in your home town, but not in the one you moved to. There are several million idioms and special usages in English, and each has its own unique history. Most of these are never studied.

Comment: I've only heard this used (and occasionally used it myself) in a jocular sense.

Comment: Like using singular _they_, _amn't_ is a form that every English-speaking child comes up with at some point in their language development. It's regular, after all, and kids love regular morphology. Indeed, _amn't_ is the original source (or one of them) of _ain't_, which started off as first person singular present and regularized to all the persons and numbers in the present negative. And then it got banned because it was too regular and the hoi polloi used it without permission from their betters.

Answer (score 6):

In modern usage, *amn't* as primarily Scottish and Irish, but according to the OED, it appears to have been more widespread in the past, falling out of use as shifts in vowel patterns made it more difficult to pronounce than *an't* or *ain't*. The OED lists a number of forms of *am* with a negative particle, many remaining in current dialectical use. To focus on the *amt* / *amn't* variants, these include the following, along with the centuries they have been known to be in use:

- 16 amt
- 16–17 (19– U.S. (nonstandard)) **amn't**
- English regional (west midlands and northern)

  - 18 ammot (Yorkshire)
  - 18– amma (Shropshire)
  - 18– ammad (Shropshire)
  - 18– amna
  - 18– amnad (Shropshire)
  - 18– **amn't**
  - 18– am't
  - 19– amment
  - 19– ammet
  - 19– amno (north-west midlands)
- Scottish 18 amnin

  - 18 ym-n'
  - 19– amna
  - 19– amnae
  - 19– **amn't**
- Irish English

  - 18 am'n't
  - 18 imin't (northern)
  - 19– amnae (northern)
  - 19– **amn't**.

(For some background on why *aren't* supplanted *amn't*, *an't*, and *ain't* in standard English, see *[Why "ain't I" and "aren't I" instead of "amn't I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/)*).

The U.S. experienced mass immigration of Irish in the 19th century, including around a million and a half [Scotch-Irish](https://www.americanheritage.com/scotch-irish) (i.e. Ulster Scots) who settled in large numbers in Virginia and the Carolinas. It may very well be that your family preserved this usage for several generations after immigration, and that others did as well in their community, at least enough that it was not seen as unusual.

Answer (score 3):

I grew up in northwest Louisiana, and we used "amn't I" all of the time! I am descended on both sides from Scotch-Irish who came through North Carolina in the early 19th century. Uniquely, my maternal grandmother grew up in the Ozark Mountain region of north Arkansas. We used "amn't I" without a second thought - period. It was an easy, natural, and fluid way of asking a question - "amn't I coming with you?" or "amn't I going to get some pie?"

We moved to New Orleans in 1970, and I never heard the beautiful phrase again. Interestingly, during the '60s in North Louisiana, the use of "amn't I" went beyond just our immediate family. The only other place I heard it was from a family in Connecticut. The speaker would have been fortyish in 1967. I welcome any  anecdotes about this beautiful and forgotten contraction - amn't I encouraged by others to start a foundation to reintroduce its use?

Comment: Hi Jbdpcol, welcome to EL&U, and thanks for a useful contribution! FYI, in most cases we're looking for *authoritative answers supported by evidence* (such as a dictionary definition, hyperlinked to the source); personal anecdotes therefore tend to be downvoted or even deleted. However, in very limited circumstances such as a question (like this one) asking about localised usage or dialect, we recognise that personal knowledge (like yours) may well be the authoritative evidence we need. For guidance on future contributions, see [answer] and take our short but useful EL&U [Tour]. :-)

Comment: It seems to have vanished even from the boonies of western NC these last twenty years. It may have eloped with *mought* and absconded.

Answer (score 0):

[Think, Therefore I Say ‘Amn’t I?’ – Frank McNally on a profound question of Hiberno-English](https://www.irishtimes.com/opinion/i-think-therefore-i-say-amn-t-i-frank-mcnally-on-a-profound-question-of-hiberno-english-1.3649312)

An Irishman’s Diary
Tue, Oct 2, 2018, 17:45
Frank McNally

> "One of the peculiarities of being Irish is a tendency, when using
> what grammarians call the negative-interrogative for the first-person
> singular present indicative, to say “amn’t I?” Reacting to good
> fortune, for example, we will ask: “Amn’t I the lucky one?”
>
> Or conversely, after locking keys in the car, we lament: “Amn’t I the
> big eejit?”  For some reason, the phrase seems especially popular with
> Irish mothers, although this could be the influence of a few famous
> ones, including Christy Brown’s, whose typical utterances included
> appealing to the ultimate matriarch: “Mother of God, amn’t I
> scourged?”
>
> Anyway, in using this form, we would seem to have the English language
> rule-book on our side. “I am” is, after all, the first-person singular
> of the verb “to be”. “I am not” is its negation. “Am I not?” or “Am
> not I” are the acceptable interrogative forms, which gives “amn’t I?”
> as the logical abbreviation.
>
> But somehow this is not the norm in English. On the contrary, in the
> vast anglophone world, we are almost alone in using it. Only our
> cousins in the north of the neighbouring island do likewise.
>
> Thus the great authority on these matters, Fowler’s Dictionary, while
> agreeing that amn’t I? should be the “expected reduced form” of am I
> not?, notes its popularity in Scotland and Ireland “but not in
> standard southern British English” or elsewhere.
>
> Instead, for centuries, the English have said ain’t I? or aren’t I?:
> habits which, particularly the former, have spread to the US and
> beyond. And it seems there is no better reason for this, historically,
> than that most people in Britain couldn’t pronounce the sounds “m” and
> “n” together.
>
> One of the letters had to go, and it tended to be “m”. The phrase
> first became an’t I? or ain’t I?. Then, when the short a gave way to a
> longer one in speech, there needed to be a way to suggest this in
> writing. The solution was to add an “r”, making the written question
> aren’t I?
>
> The “r” was unrolled and therefore silent, except to turn the short
> ain’t into a longer ahn’t. But in writing, it suggests an illogical
> belief that the answer to the question aren’t I? could be I are. And
> the annoying thing about this is that these same long-a sounds have
> often been considered prestige English.
>
> Happily, in this case, that didn’t apply. Ain’t never quite became
> respectable, even in America. Meanwhile in Britain, aren’t remains
> frowned on too.
>
> Kingsley Amis included the latter in The King’s English, his guide to
> the use and abuse of language. With typical sensitivity, he suggested
> aren’t I? “is often said but better not written except in fictional
> dialogue, where it usually helps to characterise some semi-literate or
> otherwise low person”.
>
> He went on to give his own history of the phrase, agreeing that am not
> I? or amn’t I? were the logical forms, “but nobody could say either
> easily”.
>
> To this and the rest of his defence of ain’t, (which he called
> “perfectly good English”), he added a telling conclusion.
>
> Most sticklers for correct usage claim respect for language as
> motivation. The urge to score points off others is rarely mentioned.
> So we must appreciate Amis’s honesty when he writes: “One attraction
> of my theory is the ill-natured glee it brings to believers in it when
> they hear some unreconstructed pedant struggling to say amn’t I? I
> remember that the late AJ Ayer was one of these”.
>
> AJ Ayer was an English philosopher. And although Amis was mentioning
> him in a lesson about the importance of clear English, it’s not
> obvious from the sentence whether he meant Ayer to be one of the
> “believers” in his theory or “some unreconstructed pedant”.
>
> Resisting the temptation for ill-natured glee, I will assume he meant
> the latter – ie that Ayer was a rare English enthusiast for amn’t I.
> But either way, a philosopher (of all people) would have understand
> how fundamental the question contained within that phrase can be.
>
> Ayer was certainly not a believer in the religious sense. He first
> considered arguments about God’s existence unprovable and therefore
> meaningless.
>
> Then he became a devout atheist in later life, until a near-death
> experience caused him doubts.
>
> He still preferred atheism even then. But we haven’t heard from him
> since his actual death, in 1989. So we remain no wiser about the
> existence of God, or indeed his mother, not to mention the really
> important issue for grammarians: whether, when using the
> negative-interrogative for the first-person singular in English, they
> say amn’t I?"

But, I wouldn't know.  Ain't nor amn't I never used.