# I am not going to school => Amn't I going to school?

Tags: verbs, questions, negation, present-tense

```
You are not going to school => Aren't you going to school? // this is correct, right?

I am not going to school => Amn't I going to school? // something's wrong here.
```

How to build the correct question with "I"?  Probably Aren't should be use in this case (as exclusion)? So, what's the correct form and why?

Comment: If you search for "amn't" you'll find some relevant questions, like [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i) but I'm not sure exactly what your problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say "Am I not going to school?"
In my opinion it sounds more natural.